# How to integrate the model part of a program with FXML-Controller?

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, fxml

Can someone explain me how to integrate the model part of a program with a FXML-Controller? I'm new to FXML. So far, I tried to create a constructor for the controller and pass the relevant information as parameters but then I get the warning: "Class 'some_class' is not exported from module 'some_module'. If my logic part contains classes like Person, Room etc. how do I pass them to the controller? Could someone show me a simple example of how to do it? The example oracle provided in their documentation doesn't make it quite clear for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or is it usually possible but the class cannot be accessed due to different location?

Comment: What is the exact module warning/error you're getting?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32342864/2189127